# How to selectively delete inner and outer parentheses simultaneously?

Tags: text-manipulation

For example I want to retain only the content inside \text so that

```
\[
\text{v} = \text{w}
\]
```

becomes

```
\[
v = w
\]
```

How does one do this if there are hundreds of instances of \text{..} and I want them all removed?

Comment: Many editors support this. In sublime text for example, you can select all instances of `\text` easily and remove them, next you can easily select what is in-between the curly braces and cut it, remove braces and paste it again.

Comment: "..next you select what is in-between the curly braces and cut it, remove braces and paste it again".  This is out of the question. Suppose there are hundreds of instances of \text...?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: What is inside the \text? Only simple chars? Then some regex should work.

Comment: @QuasarSupernova - I mean what I said, be it tens or hundreds, it doesn't matter. Just `ctrl+shift+m` will select what is in-between the curly braces automatically.

Comment: @AboAmmar I tried what you told me ctrl+shift+m it does not do anything. I am using Mac OS TeXShop

Comment: @QuasarSupernova - I don't use TeXShop, I speak about sublime text, but other editors have similar tricks. I just find sublime text to be super easy and fast. With four key strokes one can do what you want.

Comment: Apparently TeXShop supports Perl regex. Then if the contents of `\text` don't include any `{}`, this regex should work: `\\text\{([\w\W]+?)\}`. Search for the regex and replace by `\1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have such "bad" document where all instances of `\text` sequence would be removed then you can re-define `\text` macro simply:

```
\def\text#1{#1}
```